# How to replicate this spiral/radial stripes effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How would one replicate this effect? I've tried transforming a stripe by rotating and scaling it, but it just doesn't have the clean edges of this spiral.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Bottom Layer

- Make a pattern brush with a triangle
- Increase the spacing

[image: brush 1]

- Use the Spiral Tool to make a simple spiral
- Stroke it with the top brush

[image: spiral 1]

- Place a black circle on top (semitransparent in the image below)

[image: circle]

- Cut the spiral, select the circle and make a mask pasting in place the spiral

[image: mask]

## Top Layer

- Duplicate the first brush and reduce the size and spacing from the brush options window

[image: second brush]

- Make a second smaller spiral following the first spiral path and stroke it with this second brush (red in the image)

[image: second spiral]

- Mask this second spiral with an irregular shape following the first spiral edge

[image: second mask]

- Place a centered small white circle on top

[image: end]

Adjust the brushes size and spacing to get te desired result

Comment: Superb tutorial Damielillo. Amazing really. Ace!